# ¿Como cambiar el lenguaje de flatpickr?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un  campo de fecha en mi vista que es de la siguiente manera:

```
<input class="flatpickr flatpickr-input active_es" type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." readonly="readonly">
```

y un javascript  donde uso Flatpickr:

```
function form__date_register() {
    flatpickr('.js--input--date_register', {
      minDate: '1920-01-01',        
      locale: 'es',     
    }); 
}
```

pero no encuentro la forma de que el calendario sea en Español y no en Inglés. Espero y alguien pueda ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo agregas a tu jquery la siguiente información sobre la configuración locale (local):

```
function form__date_register() {
    flatpickr('.js--input--date_register', {
      minDate: '1920-01-01',  
      locale: {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        weekdays: {
          shorthand: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
          longhand: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],         
        }, 
        months: {
          shorthand: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Оct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
          longhand: ['Enero', 'Febreo', 'Мarzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        },
      },
    }); 
}
```

Te recomiendo colocar los parametros como una función aparte (ejemplo `flatParameters()`) en tu archivo de funciones js al cual puedas acceder globalmente. De esta forma evitas repetir código porque sólo llamarías cada vez que utilices el calendario a la función `flatParameters()` para establecer en lenguaje. De esta forma mantienes el principio ***DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)*** que te permite mantener buenas prácticas de programación.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: me ayudo y sobre todo me funciono muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada! Me alegra mucho que ha sido útil.

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar a la respuesta de Art_Code (al cual agradezco porque me sirvió), sólo faltaría corregir 'Febreo' agregándole la r.

Saludos!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/362522)